# Differences of Least Squares Means in minitab

Tags: minitab

How to do "Differences of Least Squares Means" in minitab.

I used predict under ANOVA General Linear Model.  My problem is asking me to show with 90% confidence the difference of least squares between 2 test methods for a particular score

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.